# Migrate Windows10 Setup from old Notebook to new Notebook - best way?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-installation, migration, windows-backup

In our business we have a notebook with Windows 10 and a quite complicated software setup running on it. Its about 7 years old, but the OS runs fine - things seem quite clean and the whole setup is stable, however a bit slow for todays standards.

I'm sick of all those clean Windows installs an new hardware which comes with re-setting up all those individual software installs and settings - also for me - this seems not up to date with current hardware independency of nowadays software solutions.

Is there a way to seemlessly migrate a complete Win10 setup from one Notebook to a newer one, haveing all the drivers etc. adjusted to the new hardware?

Comment: You have an OEM Windows license, while it's trivial with the right software to clone the HDD, you would be unable to activate Windows on the new machine without a new license.  How clone a HDD is well documented, is there a particular step, you are stuck on?

Comment: Yes, but when I clone the HDD, will Windows on the new machine adapt to all the drivers etc.?

Also will it run, when the other machine also came with an OEM Windows10?

Comment: There are third-party applications that can restore a HDD image to dissimilar hardware.  These are applications are well documented. You still will have a license problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may clone the disk to the new machine. Windows 10 is very good on hardware
support so this should run, or in case of a problem drivers can most likely be found
on the manufacturer's website for the new computer.

Your problem would be with the Windows license.
The new machine will either:

- Be inactivated, requiring you to buy a Windows 10 license
- If the new machine came with Windows 10 already installed,
  the Microsoft activation servers might recognize the computer
  by its hardware fingerprint and it will be automatically activated.

I think that the second scenario is the more probable.
In any case, I advise taking a backup disk image of the new computer
before overwriting it with the old one (use third-party software and not
Windows Backup and ensure you can restore via boot media).

Comment: So ill just buy a new notebook with windows OEM, right?

Comment: That's usually the cheapest way to get a Windows license.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all these machines as you describe come with OEM Windows. The license cannot be moved. So get the new machine, set it up including updates, and then copy your data over.

That will work and is the correct way to do this.

Because of licensing and drivers/BIOS, there is no seamless way to move a complete installation to another machine. I use this as a good opportunity to do a good quality installation.

Comment: yeah, but copying data is not the same as programs and settings ....

Comment: or do you mean by copying - clone the hdd to the new notebooks hdd?

Comment: I meant by Setup to install your apps. Then recover your data

Comment: the setup of this machine is way more complex than just some apps - the purpose of this thread is not having to completely reconfigure the new machine ...